# Generating Jhipster project in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: jhipster

The project works fine when i am running everything through command line. but when i import the maven project into eclipse all the angular 5 code goes with errors. There is no problem with the spring boot code. I am working on ubuntu 17.04 version and i am using eclipse oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't installed plugin for typescript.

Please install [typescript plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript) for eclipse.

Comment: i installed the typescript plugin but the problem still persists...i tried to run the application on Angular server and i got the error.

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chandra/ExampleApp-1/node_modules/angular-ide/lib/CLUtils.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.j

Comment: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here...

This error is repeatedly shown in the code

Comment: are you using angular-cli, if yes then execute `ng serve` or `npm start`

Comment: did not work..the command failed because there were errors in the angular code.. i think node-modules folder is not getting updated with new libraries

Comment: i am using angular-ide plugin in eclipse oxygen version